# iOS Swift - UITableViewCell with left detail and right detail and subtitle?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

how to add a right detail to a cell that already have left detail and subtitle. and how to give a textLabel to the right detail?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let monster = monsters[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = monster.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = monster.subtitle

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Storyboard?

Comment: I'm followed this tutorial... [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173753/uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started-2) . but I want each cell to have both left detail, right detail, and subtitle.

Comment: Dig in to custom cell. Try to add custom class cell in dequeue method.

Comment: You can not have left detail with right detail in basic cell. you need to use custom cell for that. @MartinMuldoon just explained how you can do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let monster = monsters[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = monster.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = monster.subtitle
    let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:20))
    label.text = monster.name
    cell.accessoryView = label

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi tom, Accept and upvote the answer. if it was useful.

Comment: yes I did but because I'm new here, this is what I get: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 2):

Click on your tableView cell.  It's easier to do it in document outline.

Change the style attribute in Attribute Inspector from Basic to Custom.  You will now be able to add a label.  The basic template is set, so you can't alter it. I believe this was the issue you were having.

[image]

I'm sure after you place the label you know what to do, but just in case:

Place the new label at the right margin of the cell and pin it to the top, bottom, and right, using Autolayout.

Reconnect your title, subtitle IBOutlets, and create a right label IBOutlet, connect it, and you should be done.

[image]

Comment: thank you, I upvoted it but I'll go with the other answer.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm new here, thats the message I get when I upvote.